# Adjuntar archivos mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Me surgio la siguiente problematica tengo codigo fuente que me permite adjuntar un archivo y un boton que si el usuario requiere puede agregar otro documento

Agregar documento

```
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 contendorSeparadorTop" >
            <span class="txtTituloInput">Documento</span><br />


            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="archivo" name="objetoRendicionGasto.Archivo" accept=".pdf,.docx,.doc">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile"></label>
            </div>
            <span id="mensajeArchivo" class="txtRojo"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 contendorSeparadorTop contendorArchivo" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <button type="button" id="borrarArchivo" class="btn btnEliminar"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
```

Create.cshtml
[image: Cada]

cada vez que se pulsa el boton "Agregar documento" se tiene que agregar un fila igual a la seleccionar archivo

Comment: tiene que ser desde c#? no puede ser desde javascript?

Comment: Gracias por responder si puede ser de javascript

Comment: Podrías utilizar .clone() de jQuery o esta libería https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater

Comment: esto un poco perdido con javascript y jquery si me pudieran facilitar una ayuda visual

Comment: una ayuda visual: [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript) y [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

avanzando logre añadir el campo pero tengo problemas con la visualizacion a la tercera vez que pulso el boton el codigo es el siguiente  

  Agregar documento

```
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 contendorSeparadorTop"  >
            <span class="txtTituloInput">Documento</span><br />
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="archivo" name="objetoRendicionGasto.Archivo" accept=".pdf,.docx,.doc" multiple>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" id="customFileData"></label>
            </div>
            <span id="mensajeArchivo" class="txtRojo"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 contendorSeparadorTop contendorArchivo" style="padding-top: 20px;">
            <button type="button" id="borrarArchivo" class="btn btnEliminar"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 contendorSeparadorTop">
            <div class="custom-file" id="fileArchivo">

                
            </div>
        </div>            
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 contendorSeparadorTop contendorArchivo"  id="fileButton">
            
        </div>
        <br />
```

$('#bnAgregarFila').click(function () {

```
//$('#archivo').clone(true, true).attr('id', 'cloned_t').appendTo('#datosClones');


var x = $("#archivo"),
    y = x.clone();
x.attr('id', 'cloned_t');
y.appendTo('#fileArchivo');

$('#customFileData').clone(true, true).attr('id', 'cloned_t').appendTo('#fileArchivo');

$('#borrarArchivo').clone(true, true).attr('id', 'cloned_t').appendTo('#fileButton');
```

});
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca esta el inconveniente al momento de pinchar por tercera vez el boton de agregar documento. Se agradece la ayuda brindada